# Have Magento respond to several domains with the same store

Tags: magento

I would like to have my magento install respond to two different domains, e.g.
  `a.mydomain.com` and
  `b.anotherdomain.com`

I need magento to respond with the *same* store, showing the same customers, the same catalog, same prices, etc.

The difference, of course, is that when the store is accessed through `a.mydomain.com` all the links and urls should use this domain as baseurl, and when it is accessed through `b.anotherdomain.com` all links and urls should use `b.anotherdomain.com` as baseurl.

Is there any way to do so? All the documentation I've found so far deal with having *different* stores on the same magento instance, while what I need here is to have the same store respond to two different URLs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Everything I know of Magento says it was designed to prevent exactly this from happening so as not to be penalised by search engines for duplicate content.

You can, however, have multiple stores that share customers and catalog and products and prices and so on, but represent a separate domain each. In *System > Manage Stores* add several Stores for a single website and use the same root category for them all. Then in *System > Configuration > Web* assign the various domains.

Answer (score 0):

easy enough, just set them both to use the same store code (or just default)

have a look in index.php

you can set the $mageRunCode to be whatever you want, you don't have to use the server environment variables method they have there, look at earlier versions of Magento to see the index.php file there.

see this old article of ours
http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/magento-multistore-setup-in-a-nutshell/

Comment: All links generated for that one store will have the same base URL regardless of what the requested domain was.